# Changing all file names that end with X to Y

Tags: linux, bash

I am building a script that takes 3 arguments : Folder, X, Y. The script will rename all files that end in X to same name but with Y ending. I don't want to go into subdirectories.

I tried: Rrename

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in {"$1"}*.{"$2"}; do 
mv -- "$file" "${f%.}.{"$2"}"
done
```

So when I run

```
Rrename thisFolder cpp c
```

It will rename all files that end with `.cpp` to the same name with `.c` in `thisFolder`

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Use `mmv`, it's specifically designed to do your job and much saver, since it checks for overlaps in the resulting filenames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some modifications to your attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in "$1"/*."$2"; do    
    mv -n "$file" "${file%.*}.$3"
done
```

I have removed some of the `{}` as they were being used incorrectly. The only place that they're needed are within the loop, to enable you to remove the suffix from the file names. Also, you weren't using the third argument to your script.

The `-n` switch to `mv` prevents existing files from being overwritten.